# Django 4.0.2 | Python 3.9.7 | TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'get_response'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, csrf

I wrote a custom authentication and added a csrf check middleware in the authentication process.
I am calling the below function in the authentication function.

```
def enforce_csrf(self, request):
    """
    Enforce CSRF validation
    """
    check = CSRFCheck()
    check.process_request(request)
    reason = check.process_view(request, None, (), {})
    if reason:
        # CSRF failed, bail with explicit error message
        raise PermissionDenied('CSRF Failed: %s' % reason)
```

The CSRFCheck() function is a custom middleware and it looks like this.

```
class CSRFCheck(CsrfViewMiddleware):
    def _reject(self, request, reason):
        return reason
```

Now when I am trying to process the request, which requires authentication, I am getting the error:
**TypeError: **init**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'get_response'**

the same code is working perfectly in Django 3.2

Now, as far as I was able to debug, the CSRFCheck function is expecting a get_response method which I don't know where it is coming from.
[image: get_response argument error]

Comment: https://qiita.com/shirakiya/items/1503eaffe81f91af5b9d hope it will help you to understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downgrade the Django version to 3.2.X till the bug is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that the API for creating custom middleware is that you provide a get_response parameter upon initialization.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/middleware/#writing-your-own-middleware

When you call `CSRFCheck()` you aren't providing it that parameter so when it runs, it fails.

You can try following the example in the link above and reformatting your custom middleware to match the example they provided.

Comment: It's not completely a custom middleware, I am just extending the CSRF middleware and it doesn't have any __init__ function. (checked the csrf base file). Also, if we agree on your point, what should I pass in the parameter as a get_response variable.

Comment: I believe the CsrfViewMiddleware inherits from MiddlewareMixin which has the init you're looking for.  is `def enforce_csrf` a view? if so I wouldn't think you need to call the middleware from a view, it should automatically be called if you set it up in the chain of middlewares in the settings file https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/middleware/#activating-middleware

Comment: If you really want to call it from a view, then perhaps middleware is not what you're looking for, perhaps you want the decorator method https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/csrf/#module-django.views.decorators.csrf

Comment: @artisian sorry for the late reply, my health was not in a good condition. No, 'enforce_csrf' is not a view. It's a plain python function that is called inside the authentication class.
I took some inspiration from this blog: https://dev.to/a_atalla/django-rest-framework-custom-jwt-authentication-5n5
you can check it out for a better understanding.
The only problem is, my code is working perfectly in django 3.2 and it starts throwing error in django 4.X.  I guess some internal library issue.